# Why $\lim_{n \to \infty} n^{\epsilon} = \infty$ for any $\epsilon > 0 $?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

In the book Advanced Calculus by P. M. Fitzpatrick without a proof, it supposes that $\lim_{n \to \infty} n^{\epsilon} = \infty$ for any real $\epsilon > 0 $, no matter how **small** $\epsilon$ is! But how it happens?

Comment: Background information would improve the question: What is the statement of the "p-Test Theorem" and what is "the book" referring to.

Comment: One often uses [Bernoulli's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality) for this, but @Aloizio Macedo has a neat proof also. Incidentally, foundational issues like this, where real number exponents are used (rather than only integer exponents), are going to require some delicate real analysis issues being touched on somewhere, in case you were wondering if things like convergence of monotone sequences or the exponential function (defined in some precise "real analysis" way) could be avoided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that we can write

$$n^\epsilon=e^{\epsilon \log(n)} \ge 1+\epsilon\log(n)$$

Fix $\epsilon>0$.  Given any $B>1$, however large

$$1+\epsilon \log(n)>B$$

whenever $n>e^{(B-1)/\epsilon} $.  This means that $1+\epsilon\log(n)\to \infty$ and hence $n^\epsilon\to \infty$.

Answer (score 3):

The sequence is clearly increasing, so either it converges or goes to $+\infty$. Suppose it converges to $L < +\infty$ (note that it is clear that $L \neq 0$).

$y_n=(2n)^{\epsilon}$ is a subsequence, therefore it goes to the same value. But $y_n=2^{\epsilon} n^{\epsilon}=2^{\epsilon} x_n$. Therefore $L=2^{\epsilon}L$. Since $L \neq 0$, we have $1=2^{\epsilon}$. Hence $\epsilon=0$, a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: "prove" the very definition of the limit being infinite.

For that, use that $n^\varepsilon$ is increasing and continuous, and $n^\varepsilon=M\iff n=M^{(1/\varepsilon)}$.